# AngularJS ng-repeat and ng-options do not output options in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I try to populate my select options in a bootstrap Modal with ajax json data and having used 2 workarounds but non of outputs data

**first markup with ng-repeat**

```
   <div class="form-group" ng-show="formInfo.sourceType =='api'">
            {{ API }}
            <label for="selectAPI" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select API</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <select ng-model="selectedAPI"  class="form-control">
               <option value="{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="(i,item) in networks"> {{item.name}}</option>
            </select>
            <pre>{{ networks }}</pre>
   </div>
```

**Second with ng-options**

```
   <div class="form-group" ng-show="formInfo.sourceType =='api'">
            {{ API }}
            <label for="selectAPI" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select API</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
               <select ng-model="selectedAPI" ng-options="item.name for item in networks" class="form-control"> </select>
            <pre>{{ networks }}</pre>
   </div>
```

**Controller**

```
$request('onAPI', {success: function(data, scope){
            this.success(data).done(function() {
                  $scope.networks = [];
                  $scope.networks = angular.fromJson(data.result);
                  $scope.selectedAPI = null;
                 //$scope.selectedAPI = $scope.apis[0];
                 console.log($scope.networks); // I have output

            });
        }
    });
```

the response json

```
   [{
        "id":"1",
        "name":"Zanox"
        },{
        "id":"2",
        "name":"Affilinet",

    }]
```

**Got it working**

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items, $request) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $request('onAPI', {success: function(data, scope){
            this.success(data).done(function() {
                  $scope.networks = [];
                  $scope.networks = angular.fromJson(data.result);
                  $scope.selectedAPI = null;
                 //$scope.selectedAPI = $scope.apis[0];
                 console.log($scope.networks);

            });
        }
    });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select ng-model="selectedAPI" class="form-control"
    ng-options = "item.name as item.name for item in networks" >
</select>
```

Comment: Please check how to use ng-options in angular js official documentation then

Answer (score 0):

First, your ng-model selectedAPI seems to have no value, and then it will create a blank option by default.
Second, when using the ajax for asynchronous http request, the response might be not generated on time. So you can use the $scope.$apply method to force a AngularJS data-reload. Like:

```
$request('onAPI', {success: function(data, scope){
            this.success(data).done(function() {
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                      $scope.networks = [];
                      $scope.networks = angular.fromJson(data.result);
                      $scope.selectedAPI = null;
                     //$scope.selectedAPI = $scope.apis[0];
                     console.log($scope.networks); // I have output
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

Please let me whether it works. Thanks.